# How to use a custom skeleton directory with useradd?

Tags: raspbian, useradd

I'm trying to create a new user account using a custom skeleton directory instead of the default `/etc/skel`.

Reading `man useradd` I'm pretty sure this should work:

```
useradd -m -d /home/foo -k /usr/local/etc/custom-skel foo
```

But it seems like the `-k` attribute gets ignored and still the default `/etc/skel` is used as the files (`.bash_logout`, `.bashrc` and `.profile`) still get copied from there to `/home/foo`.

Atm my `/usr/local/etc/custom-skel` contains one empty file to see if it gets copied to `/home/foo` but it doesn't.

Am I missing something or is there a bug in `useradd` or Raspbian?

I have this problem on Raspberry Pi 2 with fresh image of Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch). Not sure if this affects the issue.